# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando carregar as imagens quando chamo uma função mas me dou com esse erro toda hora.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Verificador de Idade</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Verificador de Idade</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div>
            <p>Ano de Nasciment:
                <input type="number" name="txtano" id="txtano" min = "0">
            </p>
            <p>Sexo:
                <input type="radio" name="radsex" id="masc" checked>
                <label for="masc">Masculino</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radsex" id="fem">
                <label for="fem">Feminino</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick = "verificar()">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id = "res">
            <img id = 'foto'>
            <p>Preencha os dados acima para ver o resultado!</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; rodape</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```js
function verificar() {
    var data = new Date()
    var idade = Number(window.document.body.querySelector('input#txtano').value)
    var img = window.document.querySelector('img#foto')

    if(idade == 0 || idade > data.getFullYear()){
        window.alert('ERRO ao inserir ano de nascimento')
        res.innerHTML = "Insira novamente seu ano de nascimento."
    }else{
        var fsex = window.document.getElementsByName('radsex')
        idade = data.getFullYear() - idade;
        var genero = ''

        if(fsex[0].checked) {
            genero = 'homem'
            img.src = 'fotohomem.png'
        } else if(fsex[1]){
            genero = 'mulher'
            img.src = 'fotomulher.png'
        }
        res.innerHTML = `Detectamos um(a) ${genero} de idade ${idade}`
    }   
}
```

Comment: Coloca o código todo, por exemplo, de onde vem fsex, precisa complementar sua pergunta para realizar testes e obter o mesmo erro que você para poder ajudá-lo.

Comment: Siga a dica do @EliseuB. e não se esqueça de inserir o error completo também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu HTML, você tem o seguinte trecho:

```
<div id = "res">
    <img id = 'foto'>
    <p>Preencha os dados acima para ver o resultado!</p>
</div>
```

Repare que sua imagem está dentro da `div` com o `id` "res", quando no seu JS, você faz `res.innerHTML = "..."`, você está substituindo tudo que existe dentro da sua div por essa `string`, incluindo a sua imagem.

Na segunda vez que o seu código executar, sua query `window.document.querySelector('img#foto')` não irá encontrar nenhuma imagem e irá te retornar `null`, por isso quando você tenta alterar a propriedade `src` da imagem, ocorre um erro, pois null não possui propriedades.

Acredito que o que você queira seja isso:

```
<div>
    <img id = 'foto'>
    <p id = "res">Preencha os dados acima para ver o resultado!</p>
</div>
```

Dessa forma quando você sobrescrever o HTML interno de "res", seu elemento `img` não será perdido.